# Swift: How to intercept network requests made in in-app browser?

Tags: swift

I am currently using SafariViewController as my in-app browser. I am trying to automatically load `AVPlayerViewController` when the URL matches the regex `/youtube\.com/` instead of actually loading the youtube page.

Is this possible with SafariViewController? I looked in the documentation but I the delegate methods don't do anything related to this. I can also change the browser to a WKWebView or the other one, although that is not as favorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SFSafariViewController` is designed to give you a way to present the typical Safari experience, with minimal customization (as can be seen in the sparseness of the customization functionality available to `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`).  If you want to do more complex customization of the experience, you're more or less stuck with `WKWebView`.  This is described in the [SFSafariViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/):

> Use the SFSafariViewController class if your app lets users view
>   websites from anywhere on the Internet. Use the WKWebView class if
>   your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display of web
>   content.

Comment: are there any pods you know of that can do this? because with a WKWebView I must implement the functionality of the whole browser right?

Comment: @Edmund I wouldn't say you have to implement the whole browser, and `WKWebView` certainly has more features than `UIWebView` does.  It renders the HTML, has a built-in back/forward list (history), and some other things.  You do have to implement the UI around controls for those things though.  Not a huge amount of work.  There may be a pod out there that has some of this done, but I wouldn't know off the top of my head.  There are a few `WKWebView` tutorials on blogs out there, based on a cursory google search.